# Why am I getting a Path Not Found error?

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I am getting a path not found on the 2nd to last line (fso.CopyFile).

```
FullFileLocationFrom = (see below)
ActualDBFileName = (see below)  
NoNameFileLocationTo = GetDocumentRoot & "\temp\" & TempFileGUID
FullFileLocationTo = NoNameFileLocationTo & "\" & ActualDBFileName

If Not fso.FolderExists (NoNameFileLocationTo) Then 
    CreateFolderPath NoNameFileLocationTo
End If

If fso.FileExists (FullFileLocationFrom) Then
    fso.CopyFile FullFileLocationFrom, FullFileLocationTo, True 'This line gives PathNotFound error
End If
```

This is the value of ActualDBFileName:

> Orignal - Redesign - With Partition - Clear Results - Re Group - Rooms registered - Change G-R2 Window size (Arcola Street, E7 - 3)_ROL - TEST.xls

This is the value of FullFileLocationFrom:

> E:\Hello\Work\P\Pavledes\Court REVIEW - ROL - 15-21 & 27 Arcola  St\MODEL\Orignal - Redesign - With Partition - Clear Results - Re Group - Rooms  registered - Change G-R2 Window size (Arcola Street, E7 - 3)_ROL - TEST.xls

This is the value of FullFileLocationTo:

> E:\inetpub\vhosts\HEllo.com\subdomains\admin\httpdocs\Documents\temp{0ABF2698-6F8B-4A73-9E5A-D6FD9E9E0708}\Orignal - Redesign - With Partition - Clear Results - Re Group - Rooms registered - Change G-R2 Window size (Arcola Street, E7 - 3)_ROL - TEST.xls

I have looked into different stackoverflow questions and on different forums but no solution has fixed my problem yet.

Comment: What `ImportInfo()` is this a sub a function ?? and where is it in this script ??

Comment: It's a RecordSet but I edited the snippet for clarity.

Comment: Neither of those file names is valid. Filenames can not contain `>`, and all three of yours do. (I'm not talking about the one at the end of the irrelevant prompt at the beginning; I'm talking about the one in *Rooms > registered* and *Results > - Re Group*.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry this must have been inserted by accident when I formatted the text for stackoverflow. The file actually exists: when I copy & paste FullFileLocationFrom in Windows Explorer it correctly takes me to that file.

Comment: I don't see how it can. It's an illegal filename. See [Naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), which clearly says that `>` is not a legal character in a filename on a Windows file system (FAT16, FAT32, or NTFS), along with another half-dozen or so characters. `>` is a redirection operator since the old DOS days, and still is, and is not allowed in filenames.

Comment: @KenWhite seems like you were typing your comment when I was editing mine. There are no > in the file name. I think I removed all of them but if any appear it is a result of my bad attempt at formatting the text for stackoverflow.

Comment: I stopped while writing to go find the URL. I'm not sure how formatting the text for SO led to inserting invalid characters in filenames three times, though. :-) It's important to get the details correct here; luckily I spent my time in a couple of comments, but someone wasted their time writing and formatting an answer for no reason. You should probably apologize to them in addition to the comment you left there.

Comment: My first time using block quotes :( Instructions unclear: "> Create a blockquote by prepending “>” to each line." which is what I did. I didn't notice the error. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time here. :(

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of the FullFileLocationTo: the path name is 268 characters but the Windows API limit is 260 character which causes a "Path Not Found" exception as it is unable to create the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

> - Do not use the following characters in directory names or file names,
>     because they are reserved:
>
> `< > : " / \ |`

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

These are window's rules, ie the rules window's programs follow. The underlying file system can store any character as it needs to support any OS. But Windows functions freak out if window's rules aren't followed.

Sometimes you can prefix a filename with `\\.\` (`\\.\C:\autoexec.bat`). If the program just passes it to the Window's API functions then it will urn off filename checks.

Comment: I'm not using any of those characters in the file name though.

Answer (score 0):

I think @ravp is correct. This is a known limitation in Windows:

> The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Please also take note about this:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/266e0699-ea5b-4dee-8c96-30d021709772/filesystemobject-and-long-names-no-error-shown?forum=ITCG